# list of tuples to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I am retrieving  `(root, parent1, parent2, child1)`, from a hierarchical database in form of `list of tuples` as:

```
[('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'Hardware Stack'), 
('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'SA and SF'),
('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS'),
('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NRFU-UC'), 
('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Restoration', 'AS Build'), 
('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Restoration', 'Capacity Management'),
('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Migration', 'Document Review')]
```

I want to create a dictionary of dictionary like to iterate easily and create a tree view:

```
{"HCS":
      {"Assured Build":
             {"Implementation":{"Hardware Stack", "Software"},
             {"Testing and Validation":{"NRFU-SS", "NRFU-UC"}
      },
      {"Assured Platform":
              {"Restoration":{"AS Build","Capacity Management"},
              {"Migration":{"Document Review"}},
      }

}
```

What is the best way to handle this? I have tried namedtuple and defaultdict with failure.

Comment: Where's `"Software"` coming from?

Comment: The more I look at the example, the less I understand the logic behind it. Can you please go into more detail how you get to the dictionary from your list of tuples?

Comment: Your expected output is not valid syntax. Do you want the value associated with `"Assured Build"` to be a list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of `defaultdict` of `defaultdict` of a `list` (or `set` if needed):

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'Hardware Stack'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'SA and SF'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NRFU-UC'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Restoration', 'AS Build'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Restoration', 'Capacity Management'),
     ('HCS', 'Assured Platform', 'Migration', 'Document Review')]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))
for key1, key2, key3, value in l:
    d[key1][key2][key3].append(value)

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

`json.dumps()` here is just for a pretty print. It prints:

```
{
    "HCS": {
        "Assured Platform": {
            "Restoration": [
                "AS Build",
                "Capacity Management"
            ],
            "Migration": [
                "Document Review"
            ]
        },
        "Assured Build": {
            "Implementation": [
                "Hardware Stack",
                "SA and SF"
            ],
            "Testing and Validation": [
                "NFRU-SS",
                "NRFU-UC"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

We can also make the nested `defauldict` initialization step a bit more *generic* and [extract that into a reusable method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html):

```
def make_defaultdict(depth, data_structure):
    d = defaultdict(data_structure)
    for _ in range(depth):
        d = defaultdict(lambda d=d: d)
    return d
```

Then, you can replace:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))
```

with:

```
d = make_defaultdict(2, list)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. A little new to python and not aware of lambda. Also, can it be recursive if size of tuple gets dynamic?

Comment: @MalTec could you please give me a sample of how can it get dynamic? Thanks! While I'm working on making that defaultdict making step a bit more generic..

Comment: [('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'Hardware Stack'), 
('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'SA and SF'),
('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS','child1'),('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS','child2'])

Sorry for asking too spoonfeed, but what's best way to iterate over d ? I need JSON only but just that I need add few more info.

Comment: @MalTec What is the desired output for `[('a','b','c'), ('a','b','d','e')]`?

Comment: @MalTec thanks. You can think of and read from `d` as from you'd do in case of a regular dictionary. As for the change in the input, what would be the desired output in case of `[('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'Hardware Stack'),
    ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Implementation', 'SA and SF'),
    ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS', 'child1'),
    ('HCS', 'Assured Build', 'Testing and Validation', 'NFRU-SS', 'child2')]` input?

Comment: Just for element NRFU-SS it would change to, 
 "Testing and Validation": {
                "NFRU-SS": [child1,child2] ,
                "NRFU-UC"
           } ]
just that 3 levels of defaultdict would skip it. Anyway, that might not be needed as of now.